# importrange formula and auto update?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use importrange for combine 2 google sheet Target A and Source B

In sheet A =

```
Importrange(“linkgooglesheetB”,”SheetB!!A2:M1000)
```

It’s done
But when data in sheet Source B cleared/changed, then
Data in sheet Target A cleared/changed too

What formula can use same my above formula but data in Target A do not change  after combined (A&B), when B changed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with Google Apps Script.*

#### Explanation:

The `IMPORTRANGE` formula will always automatically update when the range from which it is importing had a data change. In fact, this is a feature of all sheet formulae; they are designed to keep everything up-to-date when data changes.

For this reason, you can not use a formula. You will have to do this using Google Apps Script.

#### Example code:

The idea is as such:

- When the sheet is edited, a script will run.
- If the cell data matches a certain pattern, then the script will paste in the data permanently, in the same way that `IMPORTRANGE` works.

```js
function runOnEdit(e) {
  // We will make the patten here. In this case, the text entered in the cell must be of the form:
  // "IMPORT(link,range)
  // example: 
  // IMPORT,https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/some-id/edit, SheetB!A2:M1000
  const patternStart = "IMPORT"
  const compareVals = e.value.split(",")

  if (compareVals.length != 3 || compareVals[0] != patternStart) return

  try {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(compareVals[1])
    const importRange = compareVals[2].split('!')
    const sheetName = importRange[0]
    const range = importRange[1]
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
    console.log(sheetName)
    console.log(range)
    const data = sheet.getRange(range).getValues()
    const formatting = sheet.getRange(range).getTextStyles()

    const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
    const row = e.range.getRow()
    const col = e.range.getColumn()

    activeSheet.getRange(row, col, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data).setTextStyles(formatting)
  }
  catch (err) {
    e.range.setValue(err)
  }
}
```

Things to note:

- The pattern can not start with an `=` as this will be read as a formula by Sheets and throw an error.
- This must be set up as an installable trigger, as opening a separate Spreadsheet requires authorisation, which can not be done from a simple trigger.

You can install the trigger by clicking on the clock logo in the left toolbar from the Apps Script editor, then clicking `+ Add Trigger` in the bottom right and using the following settings:

- Choose which function to run: `runOnEdit`
- Which runs at deployment: `Head`
- Select event source: `From spreadsheet`
- Select event type: `On edit`

Visual example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most of  the formula is live update, including query function. However in order not to have your data change for importrange, there is two possible solution:

1)Create a backup sheet by copy paste data from the main sheet, and importrange from the backup sheet, so any change in main sheet will not have impact on your result

2)Write Google App Scrip to copy data, but it take time to learn