# Google Sheets: Data validation from values in a database

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, xpath, import, refresh

Is there a way to make a dropdown list or a data validated cell in which the options are received from a google cloud database *(or any other remote databases)*?

Honestly, I would prefer the dropdown to be from another sheet but I notice ***importrange*** only imports the data once, and does not keep the data in the new sheet up-to-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMPORTRANGE` formula will always automatically update when the range from which it is importing had a data change. In fact, this is a feature of all sheet formulae - they are designed to keep everything up-to-date when data changes.

when the spreadsheet is **CLOSED** the `IMPORTRANGE` won't update.

when the spreadsheet is **OPENED** the refresh rate of `IMPORTRANGE` is 30 minutes as per [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515#zippy=%2Cchoose-how-often-formulas-calculate)

and yes, you can also use app-script to import stuff. for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/67668753/5632629